# Routing between regular node server and static server?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, vhosts, hexo

I am building a website, where the landing page and some other content is based on node, express, angular2 etc.

I want to have a subdomain (blog.mydomain.com) which runs [Hexo](http://hexo.io).

On my development machine, I run `hexo server` to test the blog on `localhost:4000`. I can deploy to heroku by running `hexo generate -deploy`. However, there doesn't seem to be any docs on what this is actually doing. So I have two questions - if I had a node app, where one of the sub-directories contained my current hexo project, how would I deploy it, as if I just uploaded the content, what would trigger hexo to run?

Secondly, how to I route from my main app, to the blog? I have seen a number of suggestions to use vhost with express. Would I run the two servers through different ports, and then just route `/blog` routes to`0.0.0.0:4000` for example?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are overcomplicating things.

From your question, it appears that you want to have:

- A dynamically generated Node website that runs at www.mydomain.com
- A static blog (generated by Hexo) that runs at blog.mydomain.com

In this situation, you will want to do the following:

- Keep your Node.js code and your blog projects separate. Do not put them into the same project folder.
- Have your own separate deployment scripts for Hexo and your main website. It sounds like you already have this.
- When you want to link from your main website to your blog, do so by using normal HTML links (`<a>` tags). There is no reason to do anything fancy.

If I'm on your blog and click the header image or logo, I'd expect to be taken back to your main website. To accomplish this, just make that main text or image link to your main domain, `<a href="www.mydomain.com>...</a>`

This will keep things simple, easy to understand and maintain, and easy to deploy.